# How do I write helper function in C to return a random number from a specific range and avoid a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, debugging, random, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I'm attempting to write a program in which a helper function returns a random integer between -999 and 999 and returns it for use in the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int rand(void) {
    int n;
    n = ((rand() % 1998 + 1) - 999);
    return n;
}


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));     /* seed the random number generator */
    printf("%d\n",rand());

    return 0;
}
```

However, despite many different tweaks and simplifications of the main function to debug at bare bones, I'm still getting a segmentation fault.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "a random integer between -999 and 999" if inclusive, is 1999 different integers.  If exclusive, that is 1997 numbers.  Either way `rand() % 1998` is not right.  `%` beats `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with `-Wall` gives you the clue:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o x x.c
x.c:6:16: warning: all paths through this function will call itself
      [-Winfinite-recursion]
int rand(void) {
               ^
1 warning generated.
```

Your `rand()` function is calling itself, not the library `rand()`, as they have the same name. Rename your function. Renaming it to `rand1` works fine here.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't catch that. It's one of those things that is so obvious that it's easy to miss after a while.

Comment: @RK It is **not** easy to miss if the compiler has its warnings fully enabled.  Save time, increase productivity and fully enable warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Which `rand()` do you want? Your version or the system one? Seems it is picking up yours which is recursive and so will blow the stack. Try renaming it `int myrand(void) {`